# Change the id of each table in each nav-tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two tabs, each tab contains a table which was passed from serve side (Flask) using `df.to_html()`.
For those of you who know this technique know that the it creates the table for you and provides a class class dataframe.
I have jQuery code that targets the table and does some styling.
The issue I am facing is that my code is targeting all of the tables and I would like to find the parent and provide a unique id to that given table.
For example, my tabs are called, `nav-na` and `nav-eu`, I would like my table to be `#table-na` and `#table-eu`.
The code I have is only working for nav-na table but not eu, any help would be appreciated.

```js
function parseTable(parentContainer, regionId) {
  $(`#${parentContainer} .dataframe`).attr('id', `jobs-table-${regionId}`).removeClass('dataframe')
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId}`).addClass('table table-bordered table-hover w-100').attr('data-page-length', '10')
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId} thead`).addClass('table-light')
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId} thead tr`).css('text-align', 'left')
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId} body tr th:nth-child(4)`).css('width', '300px').addClass('text-truncate')
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId} body tr th:nth-child(5)`).css('width', '150px').addClass('text-truncate')
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId} tbody tr td:nth-child(8)`).css('cursor', 'pointer')

  let table = $(`#jobs-table-${regionId}`).DataTable({
    scrollY: 600,
    scrollCollapse: true,
    paging: false,
  });
  $(`#jobs-table-${regionId} tbody`).on('click', 'td', function() {
    let tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    let rowIndex = tr.index();
    console.log(rowIndex)
    let tdVal = table.row(this).data();
    console.log(tdVal[2]);
  });
}

    parseTable('nav-na', 'na')
    parseTable('nav-eu', 'eu')
```

Comment: Generally, you don't need additional IDs - if you already have one and know the relationship, you can navigate to it - which it looks like you're doing but then getting hung up on Ids.  `var tbl = $(\`#{parentContainer} .dataframe\`);` then just `tbl.addClass("table..."); tbl.find("thead").addClass(...` etc

Comment: If your code works for na but not eu, then it's likely the `$(\`#${parentContainer} .dataframe\`)` part not finding the dataframe.  Without the rendered HTML, it's hard to provide more useful response.